# Enable ChaosMonkey in Spinnaker

Tags: spinnaker, spinnaker-halyard

I've installed Spinnaker on AWS using https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/spinnaker/

I've also installed Halyard and updated Spinnaker to 1.5.0
Problem is after I execute

```
hal config features edit --chaos true
```

The option for ChaosMonkey doesn't appear in the UI.
I've restarted the service and rebooted the system, I've also tried to manually change the setting in any settings.js files of Deck , but to no avail.

What am I missing ?

Comment: i wonder if the situation is still the same for the current `1.18.1` version??

Answer (score 1):

There is a guide [here](https://blog.spinnaker.io/running-chaos-monkey-on-spinnaker-google-compute-engine-gce-155dc52f20ef) for getting chaos monkey up-and-running on GCE with `hal`. I realize it's not a perfect answer, but maybe it will point out a platform independent step you might have missed?